# Brownie as a package in Flask project

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, python, brownie, flask

I have a Flask project and a brownie project with a small smartcontract. Now I want to integrate my smartcontract functionality into my Flask app. But, I used to run brownie by:

`brownie run scripts/get_information.py  --network goerli`

How to do it in python code?

In brownie project I used to import my deployed smartcontract by:

`from brownie import SmartContract`

and then I was able to call its methods, for example:

```
smart_contract = SmartContract[-1] #last smartcontract that was deployed
print(smart_contract.getNumber())
```

I found some information about using a brownie project as a package here:
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python-package.html but what to do next?

I was able to load my project by `p = project.load('./brownie_project', name='brownieProject')`
but when I want to import my deployed contract from `buid/deployments/`
i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\app\brownie_logic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from brownie import project, network, SmartContract
ImportError: cannot import name 'SmartContract' from 'brownie' (C:\project\env\lib\site-packages\brownie\__init__.py)
```

I found that my first option is to run `os.system('<brownie run...>')`, but it doesnt seem to be a proper solution, and my second option is to give up brownie and use pure web3.py library. However, is there a way to make it work with Brownie as a package in Flask project?